# Unzip file and give permissions (UNIX, Solaris)

Tags: unix, permissions, zip, solaris

How could we unzip file and give **(rwx)** permissions to files and directories inside .zip file in Solaris?

```
unzip -d
```

It should be done in one command.

**Not first unzip and then chmod -R +rwx**